# iframe colorbox contact form won't submit and styles won't stay after validation

Tags: php, css, forms, validation, colorbox

I'm trying to create a contact form in colorbox (overlay across the whole page) calling from an iframe. I got pretty much everything figured out except that the form won't submit and I lost the css style and everything after validation. What did I do wrong? Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!!

Here are the codes I have so far:

**contactform.html**

```
<body>

    <form name="form1" method="post" action="sendmessages.php">    
            <input type="text" name="your_name" class="your-name" id="your-name" placeholder="your name">        
            <input type="text" name="email-address" class="email-address" id="email-address" placeholder="email address">
            <textarea name="comments" class="comments" id="comments" placeholder="type your message here..."></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="submit">
    </form>
```

​
**colorbox-k.css**

```
#colorbox, #cboxOverlay, #cboxWrapper{
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    z-index:9999; 
    overflow:hidden;
    }
#cboxOverlay{
    position:fixed; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
    }
#cboxContent{
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
#cboxLoadedContent{
    overflow:hidden;
    }
#cboxLoadedContent iframe{
    display:block; 
    position:absolute; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    border:0;
    }

#cboxOverlay{background:url(../images/overlay.png) repeat 0 0;}
#colorbox{}
#cboxContent{
    position:fixed; 
    width:536; 
    height:409;
    }
#cboxClose{
    display:block; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0px; 
    left:0px; 
    background:url(../images/close.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    width:31px; 
    height:31px; 
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    }
body {
    background: url(../images/envelope.png) center no-repeat;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 536px;
    height: 409px;
    z-index:12;
    position: relative;
    margin:auto;
}

input[type=text] {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
    color: #787474;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width:194px;
    height:24px;
    position: absolute;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-width:2px;
    border-style:solid;
    }

.comments {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
    color: #787474;
    padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
    width:414px;
    height:140px;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-width:2px;
    border-style:solid;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 54px;
}

.your-name {
    position: absolute;
    top: 104px;
    left: 54px;
}

.email-address {
    position: absolute;
    top: 104px;
    left: 272px;
}

.submit {
    width: 70px;
    height: 24px;
    background: url(../images/send-btn.png) center no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 338px;
    right: 54px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}

.submit:hover{
    background: url(../images/send-btnr.png);
}

.submit:active{
    background: url(../images/send-btn.png);
}
```

**sendmessages.php**

```
    <?php

    // Comments
    $message="$comments";

    // Mail of sender
    $mail_from="$email-address"; 

    // From 
    $header="from: $your-name <$mail_from>";

    // Enter your email address
    $to ='mail@kitistproduction.com';
    $send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

    // Check, if message sent to your email 
    // display message "Thank you!"
// Check, if message sent to your email 
// display message "Thank you!"
if($send_contact){
echo "<p style='background: url(../images/envelope_sent.png)            center no-repeat;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    top: -6px;
    left: -6px;
    width:536px;
    height:409px;
    z-index:12;
    margin:auto;
    padding:0px;'></p>";
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}
    ?>
```

**SYNTAX ERROR**

```
$email-address=$_POST['email-address'];
$your-name=$_POST['your_name'];
$header. = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\n";    

$header.="From: " . $your-name <$email-address>."\n";
```

Comment: you did not copy paste full code, see $header.=... into your code and $header=..... into my code, difference of dot "."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use below code on sendmessages.php page
you have used Post method so you have to get data using $_POST variable like this:

**UPDATE**

```
$comments=$_POST['comments'];
$email_address=$_POST['email-address'];
$your_name=$_POST['your_name'];

//echo "comments:".$comments."<br>";
//echo "email:".$email_address."<br>";
//echo "name:".$your_name."<br>";
//exit();


// Comments
$message=$comments;


$header='MIME-Version: 1.0'."\n";

$header.='Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'."\n";    

$header.="From: " . $your_name."<".$email_address.">"."\n";
$subject="Mail test";
// Enter your email address
$to ='mail@kitistproduction.com';
$send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
```

Comment: @monbee I think you have to add HTML and css both for different background for "Thank you" page. For submit button you just have to update your css class. I have already tested here with inspect element on Chrome, you can try your side.If did not get it then come back here I will give you a hint.

Comment: I managed to have the "thank you" message loaded with an updated background (see updated .php). I also tested it on Chrome and the "submit" button was showing for some reason... I now come across another problem as the colorbox is not behaving properly in IE as well as iphone/ipad. Should I post this as a new question since my original question was already answered (thx again!)?